# accessing nested functions from GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, nested

I'm trying to have almost all-in-one function that creates GUI and necessary variables in main function and nested functions to be used as callback actions.

When I have

```
function[]=foo()
A=1;

uicontrol('style','pushbutton','callback','A=bar(A);')

function[OUT]=bar(IN)
OUT=IN+1;
```

I get error:

```
Undefined function 'bar' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback`
```

if `foo` is a script and `bar` is defined in `bar.m` file it works. It seems to me that callbacks use in default variables in MATLAB workspace and scripts/fuctions in current working directory.
How can I access variables defined IN the calling function (here the variable `A`) and functions nested in the calling function (here the function `bar`)

Comment: I have read your question 5 times and I am still unable to graspt what you are triying to do. Can you extend a bit you rexplanation of what you are triying to do, what it does and what you dont like?

Comment: I am trying to call functions and variables defined inside the function that created the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For defining callbacks, I have found the most reliable approach to be using [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html?refresh=true). That being said, if `bar` is a nested function of `foo`, then it already has access to `A` and can modify `A`.

```
function = foo()
    A = 1;

    uicontrol('style', 'pushbutton', 'callback', @(s,e)bar())

    % This is a nested function that already has access to A
    function bar()
        A = A + 1;
    end

    % Let's call bar here to demonstrate it updates A
    bar();
    disp(A);
end
```

Also, your callbacks can't actually pass outputs back to the workspace of the control for which they are the callback. If you want to return a result you would either want to 1) store the result in the UserData of the graphics object, 2) use a nested subfunction as we've shown, or 3) pass a handle to a custom handle object to the callback (`classdef object < handle`)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.